# Django: retrieve table data in html page

Tags: python, html, django

I have a Django table with 3 fields.
I have a total of 4 entries and i want to visualize all of them inside a table which only displays 2 of these 3 fields.
How should i do that? i did manage to only display 1 row instead of 4, i'm struggling, someone could help?

This is the easy model to manage.

```
class Inc(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nr_sin = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    nr_pol = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already got the QuerySet being passed from your view to your templates?

Assuming you have, and it's in a variable called `inc_list`, then in your template you could do this to display the `nr_sin` and `nr_pol` fields:

```html
{% if inc_list %}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>NR SIN</th>
      <th>NR POL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for inc in inc_list %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ inc.nr_sin }}</td>
        <td>{{ inc.nr_pol }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: i have not a QuerySet, perhaps that's the missing block i need.
I should iterate over my Data and store that data into a variable inc_list in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In you view query your model to get all the entries you want to display in the table and pass them as a context variable to the templete. Later in the template you have to iterate over the list of elements and render one by one as follow:

```py
# import your model

class SomeView(View):
   def get(self, request):
       elements = Inc.objects.all()
       context = {'elements': elements}
       return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

render the table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>nr_sin</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    {# you loop over the list and render one element at each iteration #}
    {% for inc in elements %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ inc.pk }}</td>
        <td>{{ inc.nr_sin }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}

  </tbody>
</table>
```